# How to pass a value to the same page when a form submitted? Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Basically, the form has to send data to my database and my database informations should be shown at the same page  when user submit the form without refreshing the page. I did something wrong and couldn't find how to fix this. And looked at all the questions but couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the help.

```
 <div  id="tweetSpace">
      <form id="formTweet" method="post" >
        <textarea id="areaTweet" name="message" rows="2" cols="120" placeholder="Write your tweet here..."></textarea>
        <br>
        <input id="sendTweet" type="submit" value="Send">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="txtHint"></div>

<script>
$("#sendTweet").on("submit", function(e){


    var tweet = $('areaTweet').val();
    var update = $('#txtHint');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tweet2.php',
        data: , tweet,  
        success:function(html){
           update.html(html);
        }
    });
});


</script>
```

tweet2.php file

```
<?php 

 include 'connect.php';
  session_start();

$tweet=$_POST['tweet'];
$email =$_SESSION['login_user'];
$sqlr = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,member_email) VALUES ('$tweet','$email')";
$rqu = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlr);


$x=0;
$arrayName = array();
$sql= "SELECT tweet FROM tweets WHERE member_email= '$email' "
$rq = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rq)) {
           $arrayName[$x]  = $row["tweet"];
           $x=$x+1;
}


<?php for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++) {?>

 <p><?php echo  $arrayName[$k]; ?></p>

<?php } ?


?>
```

Comment: check the header request and response in the developper tools and let us know what it tell you !!

Comment: Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK     response:  Connection:Keep-Alive

Comment: try to debug it step by step by doing an alert to the html result of the ajax request

Comment: use console.dir()/console.log(), not alert.. much easyer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code...Note all changes did in 2 files..

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tweets</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tweetSpace">
      <form id="formTweet" method="post" >
        <textarea id="areaTweet" name="message" rows="2" cols="120" placeholder="Write your tweet here..."></textarea>
        <br>
        <input id="sendTweet" type="button" value="Send">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="txtHint"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#sendTweet").click(function(e){

      var tweet = $('#areaTweet').val();
      var update = $('#txtHint');

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: {'tweet':tweet},
          url: 'tweet2.php',
          success:function(html){
             update.html(html);
          }
      });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**tweet2.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
/*
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "sflow";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); 
*/

$tweet = $_POST['tweet'];
$email = /*"sample@s.com";//*/$_SESSION['login_user'];
$sqlr  = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,member_email) VALUES ('$tweet','$email')";
$rqu   = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlr);

$x=0;
$arrayName = array();
$sql= "SELECT tweet FROM tweets WHERE member_email= '$email'";
$rq = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rq)) {
           $arrayName[$x]  = $row["tweet"];
           $x=$x+1;
}

for($k = 0; $k < $x; $k++)
echo '<p>'.$arrayName[$k].'</p>';
?>
```

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tweets` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tweet` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `member_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sid_2` (`tweet`),
  KEY `sid` (`tweet`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tweets`
--

INSERT INTO `tweets` (`ID`, `tweet`, `member_email`) VALUES
(1, 'sasa', 's@g.com'),
(2, 'fgfg', 'sample@s.com');
```

Comment: is ur mysql connection ok..?

Comment: <input id="sendTweet" type="button" value="Send"> change submit to button

Comment: yes i have no connection problem. And i tried button also. @MuhammedShafeek

Comment: have u defined jquery library before ur script? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes i did. But i have lots of jquery library in my code. Does this situation cause problem? @MohammedShafeek

Comment: only need to use latest library.

Comment: run your php script seperately like http://localhost/projects/tweet2.php

Comment: it said  Undefined index: tweet  for this code: $tweet=$_POST['tweet']; @MohammedShafeek

Answer (score 0):

is that an extra comma in your ajax  before tweet?  `data: , tweet,`

if so it wont work. should be `data: tweet,`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to refresh page ,so must use preventDefault but its only work with form id .So need to change submit button id with form id .Second thing is your data format function must like json `{key : value}`

```
$("#formTweet").on("submit", function(e){

e.preventDefault(); //prevent refresh page
var tweet = $('#areaTweet').val();
var update = $('#txtHint');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'tweet2.php',
    data: {tweet:tweet},  
    success:function(html){
       update.html(html);
    }
});
});
```

I think you need to modify your **tweet2.php**

```
<?php 

 include 'connect.php';
  session_start();

$tweet=$_POST['tweet'];
$email =$_SESSION['login_user'];
$sqlr = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,member_email) VALUES ('$tweet','$email')";
$rqu = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlr);

$sql= "SELECT tweet FROM tweets WHERE member_email= '$email' ";
$rq = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rq)) {
           echo  "<p>".$row["tweet"]."</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: can you please try the alert after `success:function(html){alert(html);}`

Comment: I think you miss `;` in $sql statement.Also I removed some extra codes. see updated answer @FurkanÖksüz

Comment: I dont know why but still the same @DavidJawphan

Comment: @FurkanÖksüz we just missed '#' for `$('#areaTweet').val();` ! Crazy little thing.

Comment: It made me crazy, didnt happen again. Must be something else... @DavidJawphan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set exit(); at the end of tweet2.php file. Then only you will able to get response back. Moreover, You should define data in the form of data: {tweet:tweet} format. tweet Variable will go with the ajax to your php file.

$("#sendTweet").on("submit", function(e){

```
var tweet = $('areaTweet').val();
var update = $('#txtHint');

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tweet2.php',
        data: {tweet:tweet},  
        success:function(html){
           update.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATED**
Instead of this 
`var tweet = $('areaTweet').val();`

use

`var tweet = $('#areaTweet').val();`

Comment: i did what you said. But nothing happened

Comment: @FurkanÖksüz can you please try the alert after success:function(html){alert(html);}

Comment: still nothing appeared @Manish

Comment: Is entry to the database going when you tweet something ?

Comment: var tweet = $('#areaTweet').val(); id is not correctly fetching. use # :) @FurkanÖksüz

Comment: Really i dont understand why its not working. I think its because of anything else @Manish thanks your help :)